# How can I change the gifs using the drawable folder based on the values I changed in the Firebase database in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

In the application I am working on, I showed the gif from a url in the firebase database using the android-glide as below. But sometimes gifs can be loaded late. Therefore,how can I show gifs by using the drawable folder according to the values I will change in the database? Or is such a thing possible? if it's not possible, is there anything I can do to make the gifs load faster?

```
public class gifFive extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView showgif;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    DatabaseReference first = databaseReference.child("gifurl");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gif_five);

        showgif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showGif);
    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    first.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String link=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(link)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(showgif);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Please post database structure and more detail

Comment: Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) out ;)